# TimePicker PropertyChanged Event Not Fired if the time doesn't change

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have used a 24 hours `TimePicker` in my Xamarin Forms project. The `TimePicker` works perfectly in my iOS project but on Android, the `UnFocused` event is not called, also the `PropertyChange` event is not fired when I click on `Ok` or `Cancel` without changing the time.

The time picker opens up with the time value bound in the XAML and I want the same time to be set on click of `Ok` without changing the time.

Say I have bound 7 hrs from XAML, `TimePicker` opens with `7:00` selected but if I click `Ok` and `Cancel` without changing the time it sets `0: 00`.

Following is my 24 hrs `TimePicker` implementation in Android:

```
  public class TimePicker24Hours : ViewRenderer<TimePicker, Android.Widget.EditText>, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable
{
    private TimePickerDialog dialog = null;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        this.SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(Forms.Context));
        this.Control.Click += Control_Click;
        this.Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        this.Control.KeyListener = null;
        this.Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;
    }

    void Control_FocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HasFocus)
            ShowTimePicker();
    }

    void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowTimePicker();
    }

    private void ShowTimePicker()
    {
        if (dialog == null)
        {
            dialog = new TimePickerDialog(Forms.Context, this, 0, 0, true);
        }

        dialog.Show();

    }

    public void OnTimeSet(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        var time = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
        this.Element.SetValue(TimePicker.TimeProperty, time);

        this.Control.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
    }
```

The `OnTimeSet` method is called when I click on `Ok` or `Cancel` but sets `0` hrs `0` min if I don't change the time.

The `FocusChange`event in the Android implementation is not getting fired when TimePicker is unfocused.